# PVlib Error: partially initialized module 'pvlib' has no attribute 'spectrum' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, pvlib

I am struggling with the first basic PVLib tutorial where I simply import Locations:

```
from pvlib.location import Location

# Rome, Italy data
latitude = 41.9
longitude = 12.5
tz = 'Europe/Rome'
altitude = 27
name = 'Rome'

location = Location(latitude, longitude, tz, altitude, name)

print(location)
```

This is the Output with the error if I try to run the code in Pycharm (otherwise in Jupyter Notebook it works properly):

*C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\RenewableEnergyModelling\PVLib01_ModelChain&Location.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\RenewableEnergyModelling\PVLib01_ModelChain&Location.py", line 1, in 
from pvlib.location import Location
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pvlib_*init*_.py", line 3, in 
from pvlib import (  # noqa: F401
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pvlib\atmosphere.py", line 342, in 
)(pvlib.spectrum.spectral_factor_firstsolar)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pvlib' has no attribute 'spectrum' (most likely due to a circular import)

Process finished with exit code 1*

I enquired about this type of error and tried to solve it myself, but could not get a result. There seems to be nothing like this on the internet.